# Dialogflow Google Assistant Alpha release always failing with the following message: "For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Alpha release of Google assistant not working. It always showing the message: "For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There isn't really enough information to understand what could be causing the problem. Please update your question to include screen shots of the Overview page, the Develop -> Settings page, and some of the sections in the Deploy -> Directory Information page (particularly "Additional Invocation Phrases"). Seeing an example Intent may also help. The more information you can include in your question, the better our chances are of being able to help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm getting the same error message for Alpha or Beta releases. Can't figure out what it means and can't find any information about it anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you rename your action once it is released.

Go To Deploy > Directory Information > Additional invocation phrases

and replace the invocation phrase with the updated action name.

This has to match your action invocation.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to indicate a problem with the "additional invocation phrases" setup in the directory information.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for your questions.
Go To Deploy > Directory Information > Additional invocation phrases.
You have to add "talk to" for the invocation phrases.
"talk to 00000".

Comment: I added this phrase yet am still seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but the key is to make sure the invocation in `Deploy > Directory Information > Additional invocation phrases` matches the phrase in `Develop -> Invocation -> Display name`.

So, if your display name is `example action`, your invocation phrase would be
`talk to example action`