# Dialogflow Google Assistant Alpha Release For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to release the alpha version of my app, and I'm getting an error for my build.

> For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly.

This will be my very first build for my app.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dialogflow Google Assistant Alpha release always failing with the following message: "For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63355520/dialogflow-google-assistant-alpha-release-always-failing-with-the-following-mess)

Comment: Hello @SehBdNY, the link above covers the same issue reported by the community, just check out the solutions provided and post here your concerns if it was not helpful, following the general Stackoverflow [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).